# Controlling Channel Members in MS Teams using Graph -API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Does anyone aware how to control members in each channels in Microsoft Teams via Graph API. Our requirement is slightly different. We want General channel to be used for communicating with our Helpdesk and customers. And we would like to give privileges to customer to add their company members and interact with them on a daily basis.

Is there any way to achieve this using Graph API?

Comment: Access is not controlled per channel -- it's an incredibly popular [request on UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/16911079-support-for-private-channels) but not something that has been implemented. Do you mean to have customers add members to the Team?

Comment: @LisaJ Yes. Ex: if the company x has some employees and they want to discuss something between them before they come back to us. They know who is the right person to discuss internally. So we allow them to add their internal users in their own channel.